# About the ERF function (Characteristic Function of the Gaussian Distribution)

Tags: statistics, complex-integration, gaussian

Can someone explain to me why that is an $\frac{1}{2}$ multiplying the result of this integral (I think I can understand the rest. I did the calculations, but can't find this $1/2$):

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \ \ e^{ikx \ - \ x^{2}/2\sigma} \ dx = -\frac{1}{2}\ \ i \ \ e^{-k^2\sigma/2} \operatorname{erfi} \bigg( \frac{k\sigma + ix}{\sqrt2\sqrt\sigma} \bigg) $$

where the $ \operatorname{erfi} $ is the imaginary error function defined by:

$$ \operatorname{erfi} (z) = -i \operatorname{erf} (iz)$$

You can go to wolfram alpha to see what I'm talking about (copy and paste the following):

integrate (1/((2*pi*o)^(1/2)))*e^(i*k*x - (x^2/(2*o))) dx

https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Note: I know that are other ways to obtain the Characteristic Function of the Gaussian Distribution, this is just a curiosity that emerged from doing $ \  g(k) = \langle e^{ikx} \rangle$.

Comment: Tip: use ```\text{}``` to format text in MathJax. $\text{erf}$ versus $erf$.

Comment: @K.defaoite That's bad advice: \operatorname{} should be used rather than \text{} because it affords context-dependent spacing. Thus the space to the left and right of $\operatorname{kos}$ in $5\operatorname{kos}3$ and $5\operatorname{kos}(3)$ (with \operatorname{}) is not seen in $5\text{kos}3$ (with \text{}). And notice that the space to the right is smaller in the second example than in the first, with no need to adjust that manually.

Comment: @Michael Hardy I didn't know that command existed. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on.  First, the $\exp(-x^2)$ versus the $\exp(-x^2/2)$ in the integrands of the physicists' $\operatorname{erf}$ function and the probabalists' $\Phi$ function induces some change-of-variables scale factor.  Second, the fact that $\sup_{x,y}|\operatorname{erf}(x)-\operatorname{erf}(y)|=2$ but $\sup_{x,y}|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)|=1$, which is to say, the $\operatorname{erf}$ function is not a cumulative distribution function. Keeping track of these differences is a matter of careful bookkeeping, the bottom line of which is   your $1/2$.

In summary, the $1/2$ is an artifact of using the $\operatorname{erf}$ function, part of the "cost of doing business" that way.  See the Wikipedia page on the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) for further details.  Probabalists work with the normal density $\varphi(x)=\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and its indefinite integral $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\varphi(t)\,dt$. You can check that $\Phi(x)=(1+\operatorname{erf}(x/\sqrt 2))/2;$ that's the source of your $1/2$.

Comment: My comment below the question explains my edit to this answer. You really ought to know about this if you're using LaTeX or MathJax.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks; I'll try to remember to do this.